# Web3js shows Contract Address as null after deployment

Tags: web3js, contract-invocation

I am using **web3.js** to deploy a contract. I am also using **Ganache** to mock the network and visualise the accounts.

When the code below executes, the contract gets created, and Ganache shows a successful transaction **with the contract address displayed**, however the `contract.options.address` is null, not matter where I try to print it.

```
web3.eth.getAccounts().then(accounts => {
    const customerAddr = accounts[0];
    let contract = new web3.eth.Contract(ContractConfigs.ABI);
    contract.deploy({ data: ContractConfigs.ByteCode.object })
    .send({
        gas: ContractConfigs.GasFees,
        from: customerAddr,
        value: price
    }, () => {
        console.log(contract.options.address); // null
    });
}).catch(err => { console.log(err); });
```

Is there anything wrong I am doing? Also, I am okay with any other way to get the address of the contract if any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
    send({...}, () => {
        console.log(contract.options.address); // null
    });
```

To this:

```
    .send({...}).on('receipt', (receipt) => {
      console.log(receipt.contractAddress); // 0xf4cb...
    });
```

Comment: This fired an error, it looks like `receipt` don't get passed to the callback, but it gave me a hint to try `.on('receipt', (receipt) => { console.log(receipt.contractAddress); }` instead of the callback, and it worked! Thanks.

Comment: @AhmedHammad: You're welcome, feel free to update the answer :)